# ProgressBar won't update from another thread after a while

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I'm trying to update a ProgressBar and a TextBlock from another thread. I'm doing it using this code:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    myProgressBar.SetValue(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, Convert.ToDouble(70));
                    myPopupText.Text = "BinaryFile succesfully created. Sending to deserialize";
                }));
```

This work for a while, but after the execution of a sentence that takes 10 seconds (approx), if I use that code again (with different values, of course) the GUI won't update, neither the ProgressBar nor the TextBlock.

The sentence I mention has nothing to do with the GUI. Am I missing something?

**EDIT - More Code**
Here is some more code:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    myProgressBar.SetValue(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, Convert.ToDouble(70));
                    myPopupText.Text = "BinaryFile succesfully created. Sending to deserialize";
                }));
Thread.Sleep(1000);
lock (sLock)
                {
                    lSent = mCampaignDecryptor.SendAlCommandsToPrinter();
                }

            if (lSent)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    myProgressBar.SetValue(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, Convert.ToDouble(100));
                    myPopupText.Text = "The Campaign was succesfully downloaded";
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    grdBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                }));
            }
```

The first GUI update (that it's not the first in my code) works. The second one (that would be the last) doesn't.

PS- lSent is true.

Comment: Try using `myProgressBar.ReportProgress(int)` method.

Comment: or set different values every time you call this method =P

Comment: I'm not using BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I do set different values lol xD

Comment: Can you provide enough code to replicate the issue, in as short of a snippet as is still possible?

Comment: As you requested, I added some more code. I hope this helps.